# Was Prot really an alien?

Tags: k-pax

After reading the first K-PAX book for the second time, I became convinced that

> Prot was not an alien

However, after reading the second and third books, I changed my mind and thought that

> Prot was an alien

especially after (spoiler!)

> Prot vanishes into thin air on stage.

So, did I miss a clue? Was it obvious whether or not he was an alien, or was it meant to remain ambiguous?

Comment: Many magicians also vanish into thin air on stage.

Comment: @BBlake: "Spoilers!"

Comment: It's a 50/50 chance.

Comment: Most magicians are also aliens, so.

Comment: @Secko: not necessarily - just because there are two possible answers, does not mean each answer has an equal probability (consider a loaded die).

Comment: This question is attracting low quality answers. I've marked it as protected.

Answer (score 5):

This answer is based on the movie K-PAX.

Reasons convincing me that Prot is an alien:

- Prot appeared suddenly in a ray of light. In the station, the homeless guy feels something special is happening when the light becomes more intense. And, even though he can not see if Prot really came from nowhere (he did not see him arriving in the blink of an eye because of the crowd), he looked astonished when he saw Prot, immobile. If he was really human, it means that he would have walked very fast (or even ran) and stopped suddenly. Why would he have done that?
- Prot is brilliant. When the scientist says that only a few people (from his own team) know what Prot writes on his notes, it means that Prot can not be what the Dr think he is: a genius who lost his mind. Indeed, with which powerful telescope would have a genius (whose work is killing cows and who lives in the middle of nowhere) observed the rotation of such a star? What's more, when he suggests that K-PAX can explain its star rotation disturbance and proves it with the right formulas, all scientists look amazed! To me, it means that Prot's formulas are not one of the thousands of suggestions that can explain the rotation disturbance. On the contrary, it means that Prot's knowledge cannot be explained.
- Smaller evidence: Prot can understand the dog and can talk with it. Even though its a little bit ridiculous (everyone knows that a dog cannot say things like "I cannot hear with my left ear"), the kids are stunned when Prot translates the dog's speech, meaning what he says is right. Ok, Prot could have acted as a "mentalist" here, observing the dog's ear, etc... But anyway, it put this in the "evidence list".
- Plenty other things: he can talk to the patients and help them overcome part of their problems (who can do that?), he describes K-Pax without any nonsense, and so on.
- He disappears during 3 days (he told the Dr that he had to visit the Great White North). During these days, everyone tried to find him but no one ever saw him...
- Finally, Bess disappeared when Prot went back to his planet, and weeks later, the Dr said that no one found her in any place. Clearly, there are only 0,1% of possibility that Bess could have disappeared on her own (either Prot would have killed her, or she would have fled and then been killed or would have jumped in some river, or took a bus/train in order to leave town...)

These are not proofs. But when you add such things, it makes the possibility that Prot is human very very low (0,1%*0,1%*0,1%=0,001%)

Also we can think that Prot chose Robert's body (and helped the Dr during the hypnotherapy, accessing Robert's subconscious) in order to do something good before leaving (like indirectly convincing the Dr to help Robert once Prot would have leaved the planet).
In fact,there is nothing that makes me think that Prot could come from Robert's imagination.

Comment: 0,1% * 0,1% * 0,1% = 0,0000001%, actually.

Comment: This answer leaves out the fact that when they analyzed Prot's eyes, they found he could see sceptrums invisible to normal human eyes.

Comment: Another point to consider is that Prot was apparently took the blue bird's body as a host for a brief time in the hospital. That's one more point in favor of him being a symbiotic entity.

Answer (score 2):

When watching movie and reading second book I decided he was most likely an alien.

Point1:

> Because of the facts that porter disappeared for 3 days and none of the things in movie disproved or made me second guess my choice.

Point2:

> As for the second book similar things: Knowledge he had or the disappearance/moving act he did during tv shows just made my answer to him being an alien even stronger.

**However:**

After reading book one;  this part got my attention and made me re-think my decision:

**Direct Quote from the Book**

> Good. That's exactly how you should feel. All right. We are going back in time now; it is no longer the present. You are becoming younger. Younger and younger. You are a young man, younger still, now anadolescent, and still you are becoming younger. Now you are a child. I want you to recall the earliestexperience you can remember. Think hard. What do you see?"Without hesitation: "I see a casket. A silver casket with a blue lining."My own heart began to beat faster. "Whose casket is it?""A man's.""Who is the man?" The patient hesitated for a moment."Don't be afraid. You can tell me.""It is the father of someone I know."

:

> "A friend's father?""Yes." Prot's words came out rather slowly and singsongy, as though he were five or six years old."Is your friend a boy or girl?"Prot squirmed around in his chair. "A boy.""What is his name?" No response. "How old is he?" "Six."

Point 3:

> Why did his earliest memory end up being of Robert Porters?????!?!? He was supposed to be around the age of 300s when porter was 6 not him being a child.

I hope the third book has the answer for it.

Reason:

> Because in the movie he answers himself being in K-PAX then doctor fast fowards to get to earth, which makes a huge difference in me deciding him being alien or not.

Comment: You could argue that Prot behaves like a child when his host is a child (or in this case believes he is a child during hypnotherapy) or that during the therapy session we don't see Prot but his host, who just talks about himself in 3rd person.

Answer (score 2):

Prot is indeed an alien. A symbiotic entity that took Porter -the friend he mentions- as a host. Prot was right, and so was Dr. Powell. Except that the latter has only been able to see the Human Porter, and not his symbiote despite the clues given to him, such as Prot's supernatural sight abilities, communicating with other species and his knowledge in unrevealed nor undocumented/unpublished scientific discoveries.

It might take a viewer a few times to finally realize how crystal clear the facts were presented from the get-go. Watching the movie through Dr. Powell's eyes will always leave you on the edge, for he is meant to be the skeptic and the challenging aspect in the plot.

But the bigger picture is much simpler and quite profound. I find the ending definite. It certainly leaves no possibilities other than Robert Porter, Prot's friend is now an older man suffering a trauma as he always had since the dramatic event that took place in New Mexico back in 1996, and Prot was in complete charge of the host -likely since then- until the present July, 27th when he finally departed Porter's body/mind.

I mentioned earlier that the bigger picture of this story is quite profound, and for a good reason. This is a story about true friendship through time and space. A story about "someone" that stood by his friend till the very end until he could finally make sure he's in good hands, in this case that would be Dr. Powell's.

The real and possibly only mystery in this story is why had Prot chosen Dr. Powell in particular? What is it that he saw in him? He wasn't even a believer in the slightest. Regardless, a mystery always adds a nice spice.

Answer (score 1):

Reaching back in my memory here a bit, but the second book really seems to hammer home that prot is not an alien. When he goes under hypnosis, we meet other personalities buried deeper as well as the actual man. In addition, when the narrator rolls back time with prot while he is under hypnosis, his explanations and stories about the world become less complex. In addition, the psychologist is also able to better relate parallels between the world of prot and the lifestory of the "host".

So why was prot capable of such marvels? Many of them were immeasurable one way or another, but I think ultimately it is because the alternate personality had something of savant syndrome, pulling on the power of the subconscious mind to take little bits and pieces and fit them together. While I am a doctor, this is not my area of expertise, so forgive a rather crude explanation.

But by the end of the second book, prot has slowly but surely been merged as a personality with his host. If he really were an alien or a funny soul inhabitant or whatever, that would not seem to have been possible.

Answer (score 1):

Gene Brewer clearly left it up to the reader/watcher to decide whether Prot is an alien inhabiting Porter's body or Porter himself. I tend towards assuming he is a human, Robert Porter himself. And if not, I would say Prot is similar to a guardian angel rather than an alien, he wouldn't be material but immaterial, like a being of light. The following speaks *against* Prot being an alien:

**Warning, possible spoilers**

- when confronted to demonstrate his faster-than-light (FTL) travel in the observatory, Prot fails to do so, claiming he was too soon back to notice his absence.
- Prot also fails to describe how he's able to travel FTL. On the doctor's objection, that Einstein stated nothing can travel FTL, Prot responded that Einstein doesn't talk about those who move that fast already (like tachyons). Well alright, but currently Prot doesn't move FTL but is sitting in the doctor's office. His mass (or Porter's mass) would become infinite if he did what he claimed he did in the observatory.
- Alien theory supporters state that Prot can see ultraviolet. However, this is Robert Porter's body that is being studied, so regardless of whether Prot is an alien or Porter himself, in each case it is *Robert Porter's eyes* that can see ultraviolet. So somehow Porter is able to see in the ultraviolet spectrum.
- Prot/Porter also explains his human look by claiming this form would be the most energy saving. This stands in contrast to allegedly having visited Porter by his (obviously) K-Paxian form and to the claim that he just uses Porter's body.
- He also doesn't say to the doctor that he came because Porter needed him until the hypnosis. He initially claimed it probably was pure curiosity why he came to the Earth, and that he wouldn't know exactly.
- Gravity seems to be no issue for Prot, even though he states K-Pax is larger than the Earth and has a mass of 4.2 Earth masses. He can walk on Earth perfectly, and Bess (whom he wanted to take to K-Pax) would be able to move on K-Pax. For K-Pax to have 1g, it would have to have more than twice the Earth's radius at 4.2 Earth masses. This would make it much less dense than the Earth, it would have to be an ice planet, but ice planets that big and massive probably don't exist. But gravity is no topic anyway throughout the movie (I didn't read the books), as if it was obvious from the beginning that K-Pax can't have another surface gravity than 1g.
- Prot's/Porter's rejection of family bonds because of the tragedy that happened.
- The similarities of the names Prot and Porter.
- No other K-Paxians or aliens from other planets (who Prot mentions) ever visited the Earth, why Prot only?
- In the hypnosis Prot/Porter behaves more like his former self, reflecting his personality before the tragedy perhaps.
- Those who read the books point out that during the time he was absent for three days he could have hidden behind boxes in the storage room, if I recall correctly.
- Even in case Prot is an immaterial being of light, how could Bess (whom he allegedly took to K-Pax) interact with the K-Paxians then on the planet?
- Porter was an expert in astronomy and had owned a telescope, studying the stars. It is possible that Porter was a savant in astronomy (also stated by the psychiatrist) who could solve the issues the astronomers in the observatory have had about the Agape-Satori-system.

Comment: Thanks for the effort @john, and welcome to the site!

Comment: @Philipp I thank you.

Answer (score 0):

My theories about this movie are that Prot was either inhabiting Robert Porter or Robert Porter was just ill from the trauma he suffered years ago. When Prot stuns the astrophysicists with the information about his planet and location, and is able to communicate with the dog at his doctors house that stuns the kids, you are led to believe he is an ET. How could the doctor's hypnosis work on an advanced ET? The movie leaves the possibilities that he is crazy or he really is an ET. Since Prot had inconsistencies to his theory of light travel, I believe he was a brilliant ill man that suffered trauma. Like I said the most logical approach to him being an ET would be that Prot inhabited Robert Porters body.

Answer (score 0):

The one thing that makes me think he is not an alien inhabiting Robert's mind and body, is that when he was under hypnosis, he did not act like Prot. He had strong feelings like a human, crying, being "too cool" as a teenager etc.. Other times when he was not under, he seemed more like Data, or Spock, emotionless and matter-of-fact.

Answer (score 0):

Well Prot was indeed an alien, how can you get into a catatonic state just for seeing the sun? how did Bess dissapear from nowhere? and if she found the way, How?! Maybe he acted like Robert Porter because he was inside of his body, and Robert was STILL alive, that's why the doctor had access to his memories, not Prot's memories...
Now he had a really complex language [the notebook] and he found the way to help the other patients without difficulty. He amazed the scientists and...well.. I think that's all :D But yeah I'm pretty sure he was indeed an alien.

Answer (score 0):

When he put the alien part of prot under hypnosis, the underlying Robert Prot that he was inhabiting was able to speak.  Perhaps the alien came and inhabited his body in part to get him to safety, rescue him from drowning and to get him into the hospital.  He talks a lot about missions and this was perhaps his mission, to save Robert.  But the hypnosis part does make this sorta murky..

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question, it just acknowledges the ambiguity. I suggest checking out the [Tour](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a better idea of how to ask and answer questions. We're not a typical discussion forum. *Don't be discouraged, we were all new here at some point.*

Answer (score 0):

Towards the end of the movie Prot. says something along the lines of "Now that you know who Robert is take care of him." Which makes me believe Prot. was inhabiting Roberts body to get him safe because he was a catatonic after the incident with his family being killed.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is yes he is an extra-terrestrial, however he inhabited Porter's body. I believe he is an entity of light and can only inhabit one body at a time, which is why he consistently noted he could only take one to k-pax. Also he choose to inhabit Porter because he needed help. Ultimately leading him to help, the psych ward, where he will be looked after thus activating a chain of events thereafter.

Prot also stated at the end of the movie that our universe expands and then collapse and then expands again forever always repeating itself and we live the same lives over and over and over. His mental note was to make the right choice the first time around so that it doesn't repeat itself. Honestly sounds like a paradox but who knows. Lastly, the human mind is more powerful then we give credit for, so under hypnosis Prot could have overridden the subconscious but then that would of defeated the purpose of getting Robert help. He said at the end to the doctor now that you have found Robert could you please take care of him, which is obviously premeditated.

So yes my answer is yes, he is an k-paxian as well as human but to deliberately observe, report, study and help just a select few before leaving. And if I didn't explain well he inhabited Robert, remember one body at one time. That is why Bess is missing that is how she goes he or it inhabits her and takes her back to k-pax

Comment: In the future, please try to use proper grammar, with punctuation and consistent capitalization, and occasional line breaks. It just makes things so much easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

Prot was indeed an ET being, using Porter's body as a host.

- Appearing at Grand Central instantly
- The ability to see UV light
- Drawing out the solar system of Lyra that no astrophysicist could explain
- Communicating for the older dog
- Disappearing for three days to the North
- Maintaining BPM of 40
- No reaction to antipsychotic drugs at all
- Taking form of the blue jay
- Bess's disappearance after he leaves
- The electrical disturbance at 5:51am when he catches the light beam home

Comment: There isn't an "indeed" to be had. You believe he was, and some people don't. The books (yes, I read them) never give a conclusive answer. You read the evidence the way you want. (I read it that way, too, honestly, but it's not 100% conclusive.)